# Unknown Database error even after adding right Database Name in Mysql phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, html

I changed my database name, so I changed the name of the database in all of my php pages. When I press "save" button after entering all data in the registration form, I am getting this error as shown in attached figure.
[image]

Here is my registration form code:
**register.php**

```
<?php
// Connect to server and select database.
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "csdvideoapp") or die("Connection Server" . mysqli_error());
// $selet = mysqli_select_db("first_db", "root", "") or die("Cannot connect to database");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $employee = $_POST['EmployeeID'];
    $designation = $_POST['Designation'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $bool = true;
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "Select * from users"); //Query for the users table
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) //display all rows from table users
    {
        $table_users = $row['Username'];
        if($username == $table_users) //checks if there are matching fields
        {
            $bool = false;
            Print '<script>alert("Username has been taken!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
            Print '<script>window.location.assign("index.html");</script>'; //redirecting to register.php
        }
    }

    if($bool) //checks if $bool is 'true'
    {
        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users (Username, Email, EmployeeID, Designation, Password) VALUES ('$username','$email','$employee','$designation','$password')"); // inserts the values to table users
        Print '<script>alert("Successfully Registered!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
        Print '<script>window.location.assign("index.html");</script>'; //redirecting to register.php
    }

}
?>
```

In my code I have only changed the database name and nothing else. In my database, all fields are as it was earlier and nothing I have changed except the database name.

Comment: PMA screenshot to prove that’s the actual database name?

Comment: Beat me to it @CBroe

Comment: You should only post the relevant code, all that html just hides the php at the bottom.

Comment: The errors are clear as crystal, that said in plural form.

Comment: Unfortunately PHP does not just get bored and make these errors up. The database is most likely just misspelled

Comment: You do have another issue. Check [the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php), for how you are supposed to check that a connection to the database was made. You cannot use `mysqli_error()` as that requires a parameter i.e. `mysqli_error($con)` and you dont have a `$con` until the connection has been successfully made.

Comment: @jayshankargupta Check above comment. That may explain why you got so aggressively downvoted

Comment: I have checked each line in my code, and the database name is also fine as compared with database in phpMyAdmin, also with MySQL. And I have tried some other methods also, but I couldn't be able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your valuable feedback on my question. Now my database is working properly. The problem was not the mismatching in the name of the database, but the old database was stored in the cache memory or something else I guess in phpMyAdmin/MySQL. So, I reinstalled the MySQL, the older database was in a hidden state earlier, after reinstalling the MySQL older database was displayed and I just dropped it. Now My application is working fine with newly created database.

I would like to say thanks to all of you for beautiful answers and in future if I get any errors beyond my knowledge I will post here and please guide me for those.